# php array when in while is used foreach shows wrong result

Tags: php, mysqli

I run the following code:

```
$getytclicks = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM links WHERE type='youtube'");
$clicks=array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($getytclicks))
    {
        if($r['month'] == $month && $r['year'] == date("Y"))
        {
            foreach($days as $day)
            {
                if($r['day'] . " " . $month == $day && $r['year'] == date("Y"))
                {
                    $clicks[$day] .= mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM links WHERE day='".$r['day']."' AND month='".$r['month']."' AND year='".$r['year']."'"));
                } else {
                    $clicks[$day] .= 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
var_dump($clicks);
```

And this is what `var_dump` shows:

```
array (size=31)
  '01 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '02 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '03 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '04 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '05 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '06 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '07 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '08 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '09 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '10 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '11 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '12 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '13 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '14 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '15 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '16 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '17 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '18 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '19 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '20 Май' => string '1000000000' (length=10)
  '21 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '22 Май' => string '0333000000' (length=10)
  '23 Май' => string '0000100000' (length=10)
  '24 Май' => string '0000044440' (length=10)
  '25 Май' => string '0000000001' (length=10)
  '26 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '27 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '28 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '29 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '30 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
  '31 Май' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
```

Why does it show too many zeros?

It only has to be one zero. In addition, where the values are `1`,`3`,`4` and `1`, I only have to show them, not with zeros.

I have tried to change from `$clicks['day'] .=` to `$clicks['day'] =` but then it shows only the last result, which is `1` for `25th May`.

Comment: if fails it appends zero as $clicks[$day] .= 0; that's why it's comming

Comment: Any suggestions for fix?

Comment: Please try it as $clicks[$day] = 0;

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: If there are clicks it has to show number of clicks in integer , if there aren't it has to show 0. The problem is that there are multiple zeros in array's values, and the other problem is that it shows only last result. This is what i have to fix.

Comment: Show your expected output. We can't imagine it for you.

Comment: Try changing `.=` to `=` for both `if and else`.

Comment: Everything is int 0, except 25th may which is today and shows only result for it, which is 1 click. It looks like it replaces everything else except last result.

Comment: it loops like that: 1; 1,2; 1,2,3; 1,2,3,4; and etc to 31 thats why it shows too many zeros in values

Answer (score 0):

You are appending 0 as `$clicks[$day] .= 0;`. I think you try it as $clicks[$day] = 0; not append every time just assign it.

```
$getytclicks = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM links WHERE type='youtube'");
$clicks=array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($getytclicks))
    {
        if($r['month'] == $month && $r['year'] == date("Y"))
        {
            foreach($days as $day)
            {
                if($r['day'] . " " . $month == $day && $r['year'] == date("Y"))
                {
                    $clicks[$day] = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM links WHERE day='".$r['day']."' AND month='".$r['month']."' AND year='".$r['year']."'"));
                } else {
                    $clicks[$day] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
var_dump($clicks);
```

Comment: array (size=31)
  '01 Май' => int 0 (everything to 24 is int 0, which is incorrect, values of some are different, above are shown)
  '25 Май' => string '01' (length=2)

Comment: Yes, earlier you were appending 0 by concatenating. That's why it was showing string, Now it's just assigning 0 to every day.

Comment: it has to assign clicks for that day which are selected and counted

Comment: As you wrote in your question "It has to be only one 0. And where the values are 1,3,4 and 1 have to show only them, not with zeros." I think it's coming

Comment: If there are clicks it has to show number of clicks in integer , if there aren't it has to show 0. The problem is that there are multiple zeros in array's values, and the other problem is that it shows only last result. This is what i have to fix.

Comment: Can you put your expected output?

Comment: array (size=31)
  '01 Май' => int 0
  '02 Май' => int 0
  '03 Май' => int 0
  '04 Май' => int 0
  '05 Май' => int 0
  '06 Май' => int 0
  '07 Май' => int 0
  '08 Май' => int 0
  '09 Май' => int 0
  '10 Май' => int 0
  '11 Май' => int 0
  '12 Май' => int 0
  '13 Май' => int 0
  '14 Май' => int 0
  '15 Май' => int 0
  '16 Май' => int 0
  '17 Май' => int 0
  '18 Май' => int 0
  '19 Май' => int 0
  '20 Май' => int 0
  '21 Май' => int 1
  '22 Май' => int 3
  '23 Май' => int 1
  '24 Май' => int 4
  '25 Май' => int 1

Answer (score 0):

You're concatenating the data thus causing those excess values.

Change this:

```
if($r['day'] . " " . $month == $day && $r['year'] == date("Y"))
{
     $clicks[$day] .= mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM links WHERE day='".$r['day']."' AND month='".$r['month']."' AND year='".$r['year']."'"));
} else {
    $clicks[$day] .= 0;
}
```

To this:

```
if($r['day'] . " " . $month == $day && $r['year'] == date("Y"))
{
   $clicks[$day] = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM links WHERE day='".$r['day']."' AND month='".$r['month']."' AND year='".$r['year']."'"));
} else {
   $clicks[$day] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Everything is int 0, except 25th may which is today and shows only result for it, which is 1 click. It looks like it replaces everything else except last result.